# Trying to call for a specific method - routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes, actionview

I have user and product models. User's table has a "discount" field. I trying to call method "apply_discount" from users/index view, which multiplies all prices and given discount.
users/index.html.haml:

```
- @users.each do |user|
# user data
  = form_tag(action:'apply_discount', method: :put) do 
    = number_field_tag :discount
    = submit_tag
```

UsersController has a method named "apply_discount".
My problem is routing error when I submitting form:

localhost:3000/assets?action=apply_discount&controller=users&method=put

No route matches [POST] "/assets"

Please explain me why this form requests assets. And how to make right request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having this in your url probably means your form tag has some incorrect syntax so I don't think your problem is a routing error.

?action=apply_discount&controller=users&method=put

should look something like

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => "foo", :action => "bar", :method => "post" %>
<% end %>
```

you should have a route setup for the action you are wanting to get to in the controller

check out this guide

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: D'oh! I forgot about routes; So "post 'users/apply_discount'" in routes.rb solve my problem. Still wondering why this form trying to request assets. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've found that if there is not a corresponding good route in routes.rb, it makes the url be:

```
/assets?controller=xxx&ampaction=yyy
```

If it finds the route you get the correct

```
/xxx/yyy
```

(assuming xxx is the controller and yyy is the action you specified).

So if you are building a non-REST-ful url you better have it in the route table first.